# How to migrate wordpress from xampp windows to ubuntu

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to move my wordpress site from local xampp, windows machine to ubuntu server.

I have tried exporting database from xampp panel. Moved all wordpress files to apache directory and imported database. Used selects from this article:
https://blog.templatetoaster.com/move-wordpress-localhost-to-live-server/
to change urls to current server.

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'http://127.0.0.1/directory', 'http://server_ip/directory');
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='http://server_ip/directory' WHERE option_name='home';
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='http://server_ip/directory' WHERE option_name='siteurl';

All images on site should work and all pages but only home page and admin works but when I try to click on other pages I get error:
"The requested URL /directory/page1/ was not found on this server."
And all images don't show.

Comment: Have you enabled the [mod_rewrite](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Apache/mod_rewrite/) and configured it accordingly? The admin page and the start page / index page will load without the URL rewriting, everything else in terms of content pages won't.

Comment: It works! mod_rewrite was configured properly but in Apache configuration file   the directive AllowOverride was set to none, not All. But images still don't work.

Comment: Do the images use hard links? Did you copy the images to the new server? What HTTP code do you get for the images? Use your Browser's developer tools.

Comment: I think the problem was with elementor plugin, it creates its own css files in which it stores links to images. Elementor gives tool to change url and regenerate css files in its dashboard but it didn't work. I have been trying to solve this problem with migration for 2 weeks already so I just bypassed it by creating site from scratch on server.